# ReativeCocoa returning the result of an NSURLConnection in a sequence of signals

Tags: ios, reactive-cocoa

I have UITextField which I am using to create a signal. I have the following transform / pipeline (not sure on the correct terminology for this!)

```
[[[self.searchText.rac_textSignal
    throttle:0.3]
    map:^(NSString *text) {
        NSString* url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?rpp=20&since_id=0&q=%@", text];
        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
        return [NSURLConnection rac_sendAsynchronousRequest:request];
    }]
    subscribeNext:^(id x) {
        NSLog(x);
    }];
```

Basically I was wanting to perform a search based on the current text string.

However, the result returned via map is a RACSignal. What I want is for my map to return the response from the URLConnection, rather than the signal.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use `-[RACSignal flattenMap:]` instead of `-[RACSignal map:]`.

`-map:` will just map the NSString into a signal and deliver that signal to your subscription block as the next value. This is fine, but you'd have to explicitly subscribe to that signal within the subscription block, which is messy. `-flattenMap:` will map the NSString into a signal too, but then it also flattens *that* signal's values into the outer signal's stream of values.

In your scenario, the `+[NSURLConnection rac_sendAsynchronousRequest:]` signal is referred to as an "inner signal". Flattening an outer signal whose values are inner signals (also known as a "signal of signals") causes the inner signal's values to be delivered to subscribers of the outer signal.